# Generate n random numbers Summed upto 100 VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I want to generate n random numbers in VBA so that their sum must be 100 and they must be placed in such a way that 7 numbers come on first row then next 7 on second row and so on. I have tried so many solutions given on internet but nothing works for me. So anyone can suggest a solution or give me a link for the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was the closest thing you tried?

Comment: Anything will work for me whether to add an element or something else as i am nowhere now. Random integers numbers should be in range [1,10]. I have tried nothing yet but i have seen so many solutions provided on internet but they are not worth for me.

Comment: "I have tried nothing yet". You have 2737 rep... I don't mean to be rude, but, IMO you should know better than to post this.

Comment: You have change your requirements in the comments, please reflect this in your question.

Comment: Perhaps use Solver to do this. I believe the solver methods are accessible in vba once the add-in is enabled.

Comment: `I have tried nothing yet` directly contradicts your post `I have tried so many solutions` - Please don't post your question here without showing sufficient research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we want to make **10** numbers that sum to **100**.  In **A1** enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,50)
```

and in **A2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(RANDBETWEEN(1,100-SUM($A$1:A1)),0)
```

copy **A2** down through **A10**:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To use a macro, try:

```
Sub randomality()
    Dim ary(1 To 10) As Double, zum As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Randomize
    zum = 0

    For i = 1 To 10
        ary(i) = Rnd
        zum = zum + ary(i)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 10
        ary(i) = ary(i) / zum
    Next i

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To 10
            Cells(i, "D").Value = Round(100 * ary(i), 0)
        Next i
        Cells(10, "D").Value = 100 - .Sum(Range("D1:D9"))
    End With
End Sub
```

This puts the values in **D1** through **D10**

[image]

Comment: This solution is in excel but i want the solution in VBA only so it doesn't help me. Sorry........

Comment: @AnkitBajpai  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Hope this will solve my purpose.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I more thing i want add that i dont want to generate the numbers in a single col. i want to put them in a scattered manner. I dont think your code will work there and the code must avoid zeroes

Comment: @AnkitBajpai It is very easy to both avoid zeros and place the values in a scattered fashion..................I would need to know the region over which the values would be distributed, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114755/discussion-between-ankit-bajpai-and-garys-student).

Answer (score 0):

The below code will do what you have asked but you have more questions you need to check over: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim AryNumbers()    As Long
Dim LngCounter      As Long
ReDim AryNumbers(0)

Randomize

Do Until LngCounter = 100
    AryNumbers(UBound(AryNumbers, 1)) = Int(10 * Rnd + 1)
    If (LngCounter + AryNumbers(UBound(AryNumbers, 1))) > 100 Then
        AryNumbers(UBound(AryNumbers, 1)) = 100 - LngCounter
    Else
        LngCounter = LngCounter + AryNumbers(UBound(AryNumbers, 1))
        ReDim Preserve AryNumbers(UBound(AryNumbers, 1) + 1)
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

- You didn't specify where the numbers are to be stored or if the are to be whole numbers, I have provided them in whole numbers in an array to answer the question.
- You need to consider who random the number is, if you looked on the internet you'll know this is a difficult question
- I honoured the extra requirement in the comments section of being between 1 and 10.

Comment: Could you comment on this answer please Ankit

Comment: Thank you so much for answer as well but i think the answer given by @gary's student is much better